# Calling holder.js in Meteor

Tags: meteor, flow-router, holder.js

I'm new to Meteor and trying to get holder.js to work in the framework. It works on refresh, but when moving from one route to another, it breaks.

The documentation just [says](https://github.com/imsky/holder#using-with-meteor) "Because Meteor includes scripts at the top of the document by default, the DOM may not be fully available when Holder is called. For this reason, place Holder-related code in a "DOM ready" event listener."

I assume I need a [Template.foo.onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) callback, but unsure how to format it. Here's the HTML:

```
<img class="holder" src="holder.js/120x120">
```

And here's the callback I've added in a .js file:

```
Template.contactSingle.onRendered(function() {
  this.$('.holder').Holder.run();
});
```

Again, the holder.js images appear on refresh, but I can't get them to render when going from one page to another. I'm using FlowRouter for routing.

I'm sure it's something simple. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
Template.contactSingle.onRendered(function() {
  this.$('.holder').Holder.run();
});
```

to:

```
Template.contactSingle.onRendered(function() {
  Holder.run({images: document.querySelectorAll('.holder')});
});
```

Obviously you do not want to do the costly `document.querySelectorAll('.holder')`. If you can reduce that to you template using a class from its wrapper.

For example:

Template:

```
<template name="singlePost">
  <div class="single-post">
    <h2>This is the singlePost area.</h2>
    <img class='holder' src="holder.js/300x200">
  </div>
</template>
```

and `onRendered`

```
  Template.singlePost.onRendered(function() {
    Holder.run({
      images: document.querySelectorAll('.single-post .holder')
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Azizur! I knew I was using Holder.run wrong, just didn't know how to use it right.